# javascript,html5 and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's wrong with this code? I tried conditional operator but every time , it's same error, i.e. the control is not entering the block. In the block of function out(), the value of x is obtained from a text box, which should be compared with different values i.e. 0,1,2,4,6 i.e. values from array. Then different set of operations should work upon it on the condition being fulfilled. But the control is not getting inside the loop of if-else.
But doubt is whether i have written correct syntax of if-else or something is wrong

```
<!doctype html>
html lang= "en-US">
<meta charset= "UTF-8">
<head> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                                    

</script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header">
 <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;"><center><img src="ccc.jpg" /></center></h1>
 </div> 
  <div id="menu" style="background-color:white ;height:500px;width:150px;float:left;">


  </div>
  <h3>
   <center>
   <form>
     <fieldset>
      <legend>It's Cricket Time - Score as many runs as possible</legend>
       <label>Enter Your Number</label>
       <input type =" number" name="number" id= "test1" />
       <input type ="button" id= "tab1" value="Click Me" onclick= "out()" />   
        <br>
        <label>Current Batsman's Score:</label>
        <h5 id ="output"></h5>
</fieldset>
 </form>
  <h2>Bowler chose </h2><h2 id="bowler"></h2>
  <h3>Team's Total</h3><h3 id="final"></h3>   

    <br>
     </center></h3>
     <script>
         var sum=0;
       var wicket=0;
 function out()
 {

    var x= $("#test1").val();
    var array=[0,1,2,4,6,0,1,2,4,6,0,1,2,4,6,0,1,2,4,6];

    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20));

    if( (x!=0) || (x!=1) || (x!=2) || (x!=4) || (x!=6) )
        {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="Enter a legitimate number!!";
        document.getElementById("test1").value='';
    }
    else if ((wicket<=10) && ( (x==0) || (x==1) || (x==2) || (x==4) || (x==6)) )
    {       

        if(x == array[y] )
            {   
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="YOU ARE OUT";
                wicket++;
                console.log(wicket);
                document.getElementById("test1").value='';
            }

        else
            {
                sum=parseInt(sum)+parseInt(x);
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=sum;
                //fsum=sum;
            }

        document.getElementById("test1").value='';
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=sum;
    //document.getElementById("bowler").innerHTML=array[y];
    //document.getElementById("final").innerHTML=fsum;

}


</script>
<div id="footer" style="font-family:Comic Sans MS;color:white;font size:20px;background-color:#0099FF;clear:both;text-align:center;">a rooparshkalia    productions</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question title and text to describe better what is desired and what is observed?

Comment: What error? Whats its supposed to do? What actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement should be like this

```
if ((x != 0) && (x != 1) && (x != 2) && (x != 4) && (x != 6)) {
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Enter a legitimate number!!";
   document.getElementById("test1").value = '';
}
```

You should use the `&&` (logical and) operator instead of `||` (logical or).